# android : Error using Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to implement TabLayout in an Activity, and I keep on getting error for it.
My main_new.xml XML file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tabHost">

<TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />        
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="5dp" />    

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="50dp">
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="100px" 
        android:text="This is tab1"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"/>    

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab2" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingTop="50dp">
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="100px" 
        android:text="This is tab2"
        android:id="@+id/txt2"/>    

</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

My Activity class is :

```
public class UltimateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_new);
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1); // Here iis where the errror points
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Info");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec2.setIndicator("Info");

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
}
```

}

Manifest file contains :

```
        <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Ultimate" android:name="UltimateActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

ERROR I get :

```
 05-18 22:13:56.072: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{orange.android.vpn/orange.android.vpn.UltimateActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2131296290
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2131296290
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:587)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.widget.TabHost$ViewIdContentStrategy.<init>(TabHost.java:578)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.widget.TabHost$TabSpec.setContent(TabHost.java:435)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at orange.android.vpn.UltimateActivity.onCreate(UltimateActivity.java:20)
 05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-18 22:13:56.083: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(634):     ... 11 more
```

I use SDK 1.6 and in my manist also have android:minSdkVersion="4" . I have used http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidTabs.aspx for Tab tutorial.

Can anyone help me know the error. I have spend hours in this error. Any help is highly appreciated. Please try to help soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 1 mistake in xml file :
I had closed Framelayout insteead of closing it after full layout. 
That was my mistake. I found it and the problem is solved.

Thanks a lot to everyone for viewing it.
@yogsma, Thanks for taking efforts to help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Can the tab height I mean the part where we provide Image and text as "Tab 1" be of less height. Like just the height of text or I can set the height of it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any component in your layout with id `tabhost`.

Added the code to change here 
Try this

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

in your code instead of

```
(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
```

Comment: The id of TabHost is android:id="@+id/tabHost" . TabHost component was somehow not coming properly in this editor. I changed the code and replaced <TabHost with (TabHost to show the code.

Comment: My activity extends "Activity" and not "TabActivity". So I don't have access to getTabHost()